# Error when bootstrap toggle click and show data 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some error in bootstrap toogle when i click toggle it look ok but if showing in console log toggle like click 3 times. I try combine toggle with http.get. my code like this

```
<input id="toggle-two" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-width="100">
        <script>
                    $(function() {
                       $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
                         on: 'Lock',
                         off: 'Unlock'
                         })
                       .on('change', function() {
                         var Checked_or_not = this.checked,
                             tN = Checked_or_not ? 'rlock' : 'runlock';
                         $.ajax({ 
                             url: 'http://localhost/web.php?tN='+ tN +'&f00=123456789',
                             data: { checked:  Checked_or_not },
                             success: function() {
                                        console.log(tN);
                                      }
                          });
                       });
                    });
                  </script>
```

and this is console log when i click toggle one time but show data 3 times

```
runlock
rlock
rlock
```

i don't know how to fix it, please help me solve my problem
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
                    $(function() {
                       $('#toggle-two').bootstrapToggle({
                         on: 'Lock',
                         off: 'Unlock'
                         })
                       .on('change', function() {
                         var Checked_or_not = this.checked,
                             tN = Checked_or_not ? 'rlock' : 'runlock';
                         $.ajax({ 
                             url: 'https://getbootstrap.com/?tN='+ tN +'&f00=123456789',
                             data: { checked:  Checked_or_not },
                             success: function() {
                                        console.log(tN);
                                      },
                                      always:function(){
                                       console.log(tN);
                                      }
                          });
                       });
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input id="toggle-two" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-width="100">
```

i'm try this code in fiddle.Not have problem.

Comment: in snippet work like i want but i try in ionic have same problem, i try put jquery.min.js and friend in out of body and toggle can't move to on just off